# Create variable amount of struct objects inside a struct (C)

Tags: c, struct, dynamic, malloc

I haven't written any C for more than a decade, but here I am...

I want to be able to create and access the following items of a data structure:

```
FilterCoefficients[0].TargetSampleNum = 0;
FilterCoefficients[0].SourceWeights[0].Weight = 0.812;
FilterCoefficients[0].SourceWeights[0].SourceSampleNum = 0;
FilterCoefficients[0].SourceWeights[1].Weight = 0.153;
FilterCoefficients[0].SourceWeights[1].SourceSampleNum = 1;
FilterCoefficients[1].TargetSampleNum = 1;
FilterCoefficients[1].SourceWeights[0].Weight = 0.352;
FilterCoefficients[1].SourceWeights[0].SourceSampleNum = 0;
FilterCoefficients[1].SourceWeights[1].Weight = 0.721;
FilterCoefficients[1].SourceWeights[1].SourceSampleNum = 1;
[...]
```

The indices have to be dynamically allocated (amount of needed space changes during runtime). I am attempting to create said data structure with the following:

```
typedef struct SampleWeight_t
{
    unsigned long SourceSampleNum;
    double Weight;
} SampleWeight;

typedef struct FilterCoefficients_t
{
    unsigned long TargetSampleNum;
    SampleWeight* SourceWeights;
} FilterCoefficients;
```

However, I am having difficulties creating the structure. I am getting Break Point exceptions when malloc-ing or free-ing the structure.

```
FilterCoefficients* FilterCoefficients;
SampleWeight* SampleWeight;

FilterCoefficients = malloc(sizeof(FilterCoefficients) * target_width);
if (FilterCoefficients == NULL) {
        //errhandler
}

for (int i = 0; i < target_width; i++) {
    FilterCoefficients[i].SourceWeights = malloc(sizeof(SampleWeight) * (int)ceil(scalingFactorWidth * window_width));  // **exception usually here**
    if (FilterCoefficients[i].SourceWeights == NULL) {
        //errhandler
    }

    FilterCoefficients[i].TargetSampleNum = i;

    for (int j = i - filter_width; j < i + filter_width; j++) {
        FilterCoefficients[i].SourceWeights[j + filter_width].Weight = bilinear_filter(0.5 + scalingFactorWidth2 * (j - 0.5));

        if (j > 0) {
            FilterCoefficients[i].SourceWeights[j + filter_width].SourceSampleNum = j;
        }
        else {
            FilterCoefficients[i].SourceWeights[j + filter_width].SourceSampleNum = 0;
        }
    }

}


for (int i = 0; i < target_width; i++) {
    free(FilterCoefficients[i].SourceWeights); // **exception usually here**
}

free(FilterCoefficients);
```

Any help which is gonna point me to a solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles and executes. I had to simplify.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct SampleWeight_t
{
    unsigned long SourceSampleNum;
    double Weight;
} SampleWeight;

typedef struct FilterCoefficients_t
{
    unsigned long TargetSampleNum;
    SampleWeight* SourceWeights;
} FilterCoefficients;

int main ( void) {
    FilterCoefficients* FilterCoeff;
    int window_width = 35;
    int target_width = 55;

    FilterCoeff = malloc(sizeof(FilterCoefficients) * target_width);
    if (FilterCoeff == NULL) {
            //errhandler
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < target_width; i++) {
        FilterCoeff[i].SourceWeights = malloc(sizeof(SampleWeight) * window_width);
        if (FilterCoeff[i].SourceWeights == NULL) {
            //errhandler
        }

        FilterCoeff[i].TargetSampleNum = i;

        for (int j = 0; j < window_width; j++) {
            FilterCoeff[i].SourceWeights[j].Weight = i * j;

        if (j > 0) {
            FilterCoeff[i].SourceWeights[j].SourceSampleNum = j;
        }
        else {
            FilterCoeff[i].SourceWeights[j].SourceSampleNum = 0;
        }
    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < target_width; i++) {
    free(FilterCoeff[i].SourceWeights); // **exception usually here**
}

free(FilterCoeff);
```

}

Comment: Thanks! I guess I created some hickups inside the for-loop.